# how to get api information work in javascript?

Tags: javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#movieForm").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();      
        var symbol = $("#movieInput").val();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/movies.jsonapikey=x78wnu3hc3ve7amqeffws693&q=' + symbol        dataType:'jsonp',       
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);       
            }     
        });   
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? I really didn´t understand your question oO ...say what you´re trying to do and something about your error =)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#movieForm").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();      
        var symbol = $("#movieInput").val();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://api.rottentomatoes.com/api/public/v1.0/movies.jsonapikey=x78wnu3hc3ve7amqeffws693&q=' + symbol, // you missed this comma. supprised it didn't throw an error
            dataType:'jsonp',       
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);       
            }     
        });   
    }); 
});
```

but check this: Is your key still active?

http://developer.rottentomatoes.com/docs/read/JSON